# KDE accessibility applet respawned in my LXDE panel - how to get rid of it?

Tags: debian, taskbar, kde, accessibility, lxde

For some strange reason, whenever I log in to my LXDE desktop, I see the KDE accessibility applet on the panel/taskbar. I can't figure out what's triggering it being run and how I can stop it from running.

So, what's the cause and what's the cure?

Notes:

- I can shut it down, but it respawns after a while.
- I'm using Debian Stretch on an x86_64 system.

Comment: Got the same problem, but in XFCE. No solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer about the *cause*. It's amarok. When I don't run amarok after login - this doesn't happen. As soon as I bring amarok up, I get the accessibility icon. I would guess there are probably some other KDE apps which trigger this, but - not all of them. Probably not most of them.